# PostgreSQL: How to log the duration taken by the Synchronous Commit after query execution? (Docs unhelpful)

Tags: postgresql, logging

I'm running a PostgreSQL 12 server on ubuntu. Here are the relevant settings in my postgresql.conf file:

```
log_duration = on
log_statement = 'all'
log_destination = 'csvlog'
logging_collector = on
```

I ran a few update queries locally from a rust program and they took around 3-4 ms to return. I checked the PostgreSQL logs from the dumped csv file and I was surprised to see that the duration recorded there for the queries was just around 0.18 ms.

This disparity seemed too high to me and couldn't just be the overhead from the client application. I disabled synchronous commit and now the queries took no more than 1 ms on the client side. So it seems that the overhead was due to synchronous commit and the fdatasync system call.

My question is that why this overhead is not reflected in the logs, nor could I find any information in the documentation that specifies that the query duration doesn't include the time takes for the commit. Also, if I need it, how can I log the time every commit operation takes?

Comment: It is hard to explain to you logs which we can't see....

Comment: Do you have replication set up on this server and is `synchronous_standby_names` set to a value?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver no I don't have replication setup. ```synchronous_standby_names``` is empty.

Comment: @jjanes I'll attach the logs, but my questions doesn't really depend on them. I just wanted to know that if I have these settings in the config file for collecting the logs, will the duration recorded for query execution also include the duration to flush the WAL on the disk, and if not, how do I get that duration?

Comment: I my experience, the duration messages *do* include the fsync time, which is why I think you are misreading the log file.  If you use explicit transactions, the fsync time is included in the COMMIT or END statement duration, not the other statements.

Comment: @jjanes Please check my answer below. I think I have it figured out. I wasn't misreading the log file.

Answer (score 1):

OP here, I've spent almost my entire Sunday looking at the PostgreSQL source code and reading the docs for Frontend Backend Protocol (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol.html). Now, I believe I have the answer.

First, I should've mentioned this in the question, but my client application was using the Extended Query protocol. The relevant part from the protocol is this, if you're not using explicit `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` in your transaction, the commit (and the subsequent fsync to the disc) happens when the client sends "Sync" message to the server. However, Sync isn't logged, only the previous Execute is, and Execute doesn't include the time to commit because that is done via a separate message (Sync). If you want the time taken to write to the disc you need to use explicit BEGIN and COMMIT.

The above is applicable when you're using the Extended Query Protocol. If you're running Simple Queries, then the complete duration (including the time taken to write to disc) will be logged. For the full story, check this out: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/tcop/postgres.c

The relevant functions are:

`exec_simple_query`: It checks in the middle if the Simple Query should be committed or not. (Assuming that explicit `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` isn't used.)

`PostgresMain`: The switch statement inside will clarify that in the extended query protocol `Execute` and `Sync` are separate steps and that Sync isn't logged.

Comment: Good analysis.  It is easy to confirm this with pgbench, using `-M extended` or `-M prepared`.  It seems like the docs for log_duration should mention this.

Comment: Yup i feel the docs should be clearer.